# convert string to bool while fetching data from database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

```
create table tasktodo(Id int identity(1,1) not null, Done bit,Texts nvarchar(max),Dates date)
```

That is my database table.

I wrote the code to get the data from database like this

```
public List<TaskToDoList> GetTaskToDo()
{
    var Obj = DBHelper.GetDBObject();
    reader = Obj.ExecuteReader(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetTaskToDoList");
    var tasktodo = new List<TaskToDoList>();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        tasktodo.Add(new TaskToDoList
        {   
            Id =GetInteger("Id"),
            Done=Convert.ToBoolean("Done"),
            Text=GetString("Text"),
            Date =reader["Date"] ==DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Date"])            
        });
    }
    return tasktodo;
}
```

My model

```
public class TaskToDoList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

It is showing an error

> "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean"

How to solve this?

Comment: The only valid values for `Convert.ToBoolean()` are `"True"` and `"False"` (refer [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3(v=vs.110).aspx)). Unclear what your doing here - you not even reading the value from the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for it.

I'm reading the values from the reader those GetString and GetIngers are the functions to check any nulls. those parameter are values from database table

```
  public List<TaskToDoList> GetTaskToDo()
    {
        var Obj = DBHelper.GetDBObject();
        reader = Obj.ExecuteReader(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetTaskToDoList");
        var tasktodo = new List<TaskToDoList>();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            tasktodo.Add(
                new TaskToDoList
                {

                Id =GetInteger("Id"),
                Done=Convert.ToBoolean( reader["Done"]),
                Text=GetString("Texts"),
                Date =reader["Dates"] ==DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Dates"])            
                });
        }
        return tasktodo;
    }
```

Comment: You may want to think about your structure here.  I'm assuming reader is a member instance as it must be used within the GetInteger and GetString methods.  With this patter it is never disposed of.